# Plot heatmaps of multiple data frames using a slider in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap, ggplotly

I have multiple data.frames and each one of them represent the pairwise interactions of individuals at different time points.

Here is an example of how my data.frames look.

```
df1 <- matrix(data = rexp(9, rate = 10), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
df2 <- matrix(data = rexp(16, rate = 10), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
df3 <- matrix(data = rexp(4, rate = 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

I would like to plot them as it is pointed in this page (https://plotly.com/r/sliders/)
where with a slider I can move from one heatmap to the other.

I have tried so far with plotly but I have not succeeded. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am struggling for long with this issue. I might be a bit blind at this point so please forgive me if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the `Sine Wave Slider` example on https://plotly.com/r/sliders/ this can be achieved like so. The first step of my approach involves converting the matrices to dataframes with columns x, y, z. Second instead of lines we plot heatmaps.

```
df1 <- matrix(data = rexp(9, rate = 10), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
df2 <- matrix(data = rexp(16, rate = 10), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
df3 <- matrix(data = rexp(4, rate = 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

# Make dataframes
d <- lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(d) {
            d %>%
              as_tibble(.colnames = seq(ncol(.))) %>% 
              rowid_to_column("x") %>% 
              pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "y", values_to = "z") %>% 
              mutate(y = stringr::str_extract(y, "\\d"),
                     y = as.numeric(y))
    })

aval <- list()
for(step in seq_along(d)){
  aval[[step]] <-list(visible = FALSE,
                      name = paste0('v = ', step),
                      x = d[[step]]$x,
                      y = d[[step]]$y,
                      z = d[[step]]$z)
}
aval[1][[1]]$visible = TRUE

steps <- list()
fig <- plot_ly()

for (i in seq_along(aval)) {
  fig <- add_trace(fig, x = aval[i][[1]]$x, y = aval[i][[1]]$y, z = aval[i][[1]]$z, visible = aval[i][[1]]$visible, 
                   name = aval[i][[1]]$name, type = "heatmap")
  fig
  step <- list(args = list('visible', rep(FALSE, length(aval))), method = 'restyle')
  
  step$args[[2]][i] = TRUE  
  steps[[i]] = step
}

fig <- fig %>%
  layout(sliders = list(list(active = 0,
                             currentvalue = list(prefix = "Heatmap: "),
                             steps = steps)))
fig
```

[image]